# Regex search for a phrase, return 'n' characters after phrase

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a large amount of text (lyrics) that I'm trying to search through. When a certain phrase, "higher than" appears, I want the code to return only the next 10 characters.

Ex. "blah blah I'm higher than a plane in the sky blah blah blah" would return "a plane in"

I can't seem to combine the .match or .substr methods, and I'm not sure how to phrase my initial regex search without having to have a ton of [/s/S] character sets. i'm looking at the .match method because I want an array of information for words following the given phrase.

I'm stuck at    `/(higher than [\s\S][\s\S])/igm`      for the moment.

Any help appreciated. New to JS, apologies in advance.

Comment: Use `/(higher than .{10})/i`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a repeatation quantifier `{}` to specify the range.

```
/higher than ([\s\S]{10})/igm
```

And get the string you want from group index 1.

```
> var str = "blah blah I'm higher than a plane in the sky blah blah blah"
undefined
> var re = /higher than ([\s\S]{10})/gmi;
undefined
> var s = []
undefined
> var m;
undefined
> while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
... s.push(m[1]);
... }
1
> s
[ 'a plane in' ]
```